# Summing up consecutive values for each sequence in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin, livy

I have a data set where I have sequence numbers say 0's and 1's.

```
Category   Value    Sequences
  1         10        0
  1         11        1
  1         13        1
  1         16        1
  1         20        0
  1         21        0
  1         22        1
  1         25        1
  1         27        1
  1         29        1
  1         30        0
  1         32        1
  1         34        1
  1         35        1
  1         38        0
```

Here the 1's in sequences column occurs thrice. I need to sum up that sequence value alone.

I'm trying this by using the below code:

```
%livy2.spark
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

val df = df.select( $"Category", $"Value", $"Sequences").rdd.groupBy(x => 
(x.getInt(0)) 
 ).map(
   x => { 
      val Category= x(0).getInt(0)
      val Value= x(0).getInt(1)
      val Sequences = x(0).getInt(2)
      for (i <- x.indices){
         val vi = x(i).getFloat(4)
         if (vi(0) >0 )                 
             { 
               summing+  = Value//  
            } 
  (Category, summing)
 }
 }
 )
 df_new.take(10).foreach(println)
```

When I wrote this code error occurs stating that incomplete statement.
The value df represents the data set which i gave initially.

The expected output is:

```
Category   summing 
  1         40
  1         103
  1         101
```

I don't know where i'm lagging. It would be great if someone help me in learning out this new thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be done by assigning each row unique id, and then including each unit in group specified by next zero unique id:

```
val df = Seq(
  (1, 10, 0),
  (1, 11, 1),
  (1, 13, 1),
  (1, 16, 1),
  (1, 20, 0),
  (1, 21, 0),
  (1, 22, 1),
  (1, 25, 1),
  (1, 27, 1),
  (1, 29, 1),
  (1, 30, 0),
  (1, 32, 1),
  (1, 34, 1),
  (1, 35, 1),
  (1, 38, 0)
).toDF("Category", "Value", "Sequences")

// assign each row unique id
val zipped = df.withColumn("zip", monotonically_increasing_id())

// Make range from zero to next zero
val categoryWindow = Window.partitionBy("Category").orderBy($"zip")
val groups = zipped
  .filter($"Sequences" === 0)
  .withColumn("rangeEnd", lead($"zip", 1).over(categoryWindow))
  .withColumnRenamed("zip", "rangeStart")

println("Groups:")
groups.show(false)

// Assign range for each unit
val joinCondition = ($"units.zip" > $"groups.rangeStart").and($"units.zip" < $"groups.rangeEnd")
val unitsByRange = zipped
  .filter($"Sequences" === 1).alias("units")
  .join(groups.alias("groups"), joinCondition, "left")
  .select("units.Category", "units.Value", "groups.rangeStart")

println("Units in groups:")
unitsByRange.show(false)

// Group by range
val result = unitsByRange
  .groupBy($"Category", $"rangeStart")
  .agg(sum("Value").alias("summing"))
  .orderBy("rangeStart")
  .drop("rangeStart")

println("Result:")
result.show(false)
```

Output:

```
Groups:
+--------+-----+---------+----------+----------+
|Category|Value|Sequences|rangeStart|rangeEnd  |
+--------+-----+---------+----------+----------+
|1       |10   |0        |0         |4         |
|1       |20   |0        |4         |5         |
|1       |21   |0        |5         |8589934595|
|1       |30   |0        |8589934595|8589934599|
|1       |38   |0        |8589934599|null      |
+--------+-----+---------+----------+----------+

Units in groups:
+--------+-----+----------+
|Category|Value|rangeStart|
+--------+-----+----------+
|1       |11   |0         |
|1       |13   |0         |
|1       |16   |0         |
|1       |22   |5         |
|1       |25   |5         |
|1       |27   |5         |
|1       |29   |5         |
|1       |32   |8589934595|
|1       |34   |8589934595|
|1       |35   |8589934595|
+--------+-----+----------+

Result:
+--------+-------+
|Category|summing|
+--------+-------+
|1       |40     |
|1       |103    |
|1       |101    |
+--------+-------+
```